# Can I land in Dublin and drive up to start my worker visa in Northern Ireland?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, ireland

I am an American moving to Northern Ireland on a Tier 2 visa. On our official move date, do I need to land in Northern Ireland (UK) or can I land in Dublin and drive up?

My concern is getting through Irish immigration and also not having an official 'start day' stamped on my passport for my tier 2. No border = No stamp/official start date, right?

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine entering at Dublin.

Your permission to work in the UK is established not by a stamp at the border but rather by the possession of a [biometric residence permit](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/collect). You'll be collecting your BRP either from a Post Office you chose or from your sponsor; your decision letter should tell you this. The person you collect the card from will be interested in when you arrived in the UK so you should try to keep evidence of that, though if you travel up within a day or so of your arrival at Dublin the Ireland arrival stamp in your passport is likely fine.

[The response to this FOI request](https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/non_eu_citizen_entering_uk_north) says the same thing. There isn't a problem